# What do i need to do when i tried to update my windows 8.1 phone to windows 10 and i can't turn it on now?

Tags: windows-10, insider-preview

I yesterday saw a video how you could update your phone and i liked to do that but now i can't turn on my phone beacouse this keeps happening: i try to turn on my phone, the nokia flash appears, then the Windows sign and beneath that windows sign there is writen: not for resale, after that it keeps doing the same thing over and over again..

Comment: After 5 hours of doing this my phone turned on ( it whas still charching the hole time) and now it is working like it should thanks to: Microsoft